# Deploying ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC app to Server doesn't work

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc, web-deployment, visual-studio-2022

I am new to web development, I am learning it on the way as I develop my application.

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app that basically does this:

- Starts with a Login
- After login you can view the data
- You can manipulate data on the view page
- You can view some logs, and acknowledge them

So, my app works just fine when I run it from VS 2022.

I would like to deploy the app, so it can be used within the company. It all works on an internal network.

I have two options for deployment and to host the app from:

- Windows Server 2019 (IIS)
- Synology NAS

It really doesn't matter for me, but I have been through more than a dozen of tutorials/videos, but could not get it work either way.

I have tried different publishing methods.

I have .NET Core Hosting 7.0.2 and Web Deployment installed on the Windows server.

Basically my published file structure doesn't look like in some of the tutorials.

The furthest I've got is that I can load the page on the Windows Server 2019 machine, it shows the login page, but after I press "Login" it says ".../LoginController" Page not found.

So, after this chaos, can anyone give me some guidance where should I look for the solution? I thought it would be a good idea to use MVC, but now I think it would be much easier with a simple ASP Web app...

Comment: If you have an ASP.NET Core **6.0** app - why do you try to use ASP.NET Core **7.0** hosting package??

Comment: @marc_s Well, I found that first, and thought that is backward compatible. Sorry for being so naive :)

Comment: It probably will be - to a degree. But as long as you don't plan on hosting any .NET 7 projects - why not just use the "proper" (most compatible) hosting - .NET 6 for .NET 6 apps - just a thought :-)

Comment: @marc_s Yeah, I have installed it, I could get along to the point that it loads (just as before) turns out I had another problem (I will write it as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, after I got to the Login page (as I mentioned), I figured out the problem there. I am using cookies, which were set to "secure" in the program, but I was usint http instead of https. As a test, I have set the cookies' "Secure" property to "false", after that it worked.

At least I know where to go next.